# how to remove null value in dataset and cause to show complete data in table view in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

I encountered a problem that when I import Excel data in Power BI, the data is displayed as null data in the table view section and other data is hidden, and how can this null data be changed in the Power Queray section and Show the data completely in the table view?

[image]

Comment: What do you see in Power Query? You can obviously calculate the duration in seconds  based on your `Time` column. Satisfaction rating is not inferrable from your data. Not sure if `Average talk duration` is something I would want in a fact table like this.